# What's the meaning of " wildness" in this context? Could it mean our nature/essence that we were born with?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

. He tried to shape in his mind what he had to say to McDonald. It was a feeling; it was an urge that he had to speak. But whatever he spoke he knew would be but another name for the **wildness** that he sought. It was a freedom and a goodness, a hope and a vigor that he perceived to underlie all the familiar things of his life, which were not free or good or hopeful or vigorous. What he sought was the source and preserver of his world, a world which seemed to turn ever in fear away from its source, rather than search it out, as the prairie grass around him sent down its fibered roots into the rich dark dampness, the **Wildness**, and thereby renewed itself, year after year.

Comment: Hello So Gh,  This is not a question of English Learning.  It may be a question of [literature.se] interpretation. Wilderness doesn't mean "the essence that we are born with". Perhaps this is an interpretation of what message the author was giving. But that is beyond the scope of this stack exchange.

Comment: You also haven't told us the source of the text, and why you think the usual dictionary definition of "wilderness" isn't applicable here.

Comment: The migration to this stack was a mistake by the Mods on [English.se]

Comment: @JamesK hello james k, at first thank you for replying. I asked this at English Language & Usage but it was migrated here and I don't know why this happend . However I agree with you , this question is related to literature interpretation but I must add this the word I asked about is the " wildness" not " wilderness" that means " an uncultivated, uninhabited, and inhospitable region" .the source of the text is  a novel by john williams called Butcher's Crossing.

Comment: @SoGh Do you have a source text that you can share with us to show exactly where this is? But also, the text itself is defining for you what “wildness” represents, so I’m not sure exactly what you’re asking about.

Comment: @AnnabethYeung thank you for the reply. This is a paragraph of a novel called Butcher's Crossing and it is about a boy who left his college and home and set out a journey to the west so here he wanted to describe his feeling  and the reason why he came out there and what he sought for , but he couldn't find the proper word .with " the text is defining " You mean that this part defines the word wildness: " It was a freedom and a goodness, a hope and a vigor "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given my relatively limited context, it seems to me that **“wildness”** is being used to describe an indescribable feeling, so to speak. The text says that **wildness** is a sense of freedom or of energy and vigor. In other words, positive force. In the context that you have provided for the novel, it seems that the boy is trying to say that he left home in order to seek this force, which he perceived as underlying all the things in his life. So there is no proper “dictionary definition” for how it’s being used in this text. You just have to gain a general understanding of what this character is referring to.

The passage that you written out is rather abstract to begin with. The main character of this passage is saying that while **wildness** is kind of a positive/energetic force, it underlies aspects of his life that are anything but. He’s saying that **wildness** sustains his world, but the things in his world reject and fear **wildness**, and this character wants to actively seek it out instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.wildness has a negative meaning generally but here as you explain it has a positive meaning.if i have understood it right.

Comment: I think the best way to see its connotation is as **neutral**. “Wildness” is supposed to be kind of mysterious, so given what I know from this text, it seems more appropriate to keep it neutral.

Comment: @ Annabeth Yeung Many thanks